# Get my HTML 5 App to open on the last viewed page

Tags: android, iphone, html, hybrid

Okay, so here's my problem:

I have a web app which I go to the website for, save to my home screen and I have the icon for it on the home screen. That works and is great. Now, any time I press on this icon, it loads the home page (index.html) This isn't really what I'm after. Ideally, I want it to open from the last known position, just like an app would. Say if I had browsed to interesting.html, pressed the home button and gone into some other app and come back later, I would expect it to open up on interesting.html. How would you go about telling the phone to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use HTML5 local storage to save state based on certain behaviours you deem as a change of state, then retrieve and load that state on page load. If you didn't want to rely on HTML5 local storage, then you could use AJAX to send state back to your server for authenticated users, again retrieve and loading on the next page load...this could also be a feature, if say the app was complex and it might be favourable for the state to be persisted over multiple devices. Depending on your needs, maybe even a simple cookie would suffice

Comment: I see how localstorage could be used, it just feels a bit 'hacky', was hoping there was a cleaner way, such as use of the meta tags to specify it's viewport, although that's a slightly different thing I guess.